Jenkins job runs infinite after mvn install
i have created a pipeline job in Jenkins where i use the following Jenkinsfile:
def remote=[:]
remote.name = 'ec2-user'
remote.host = '3.85.186.135'  
remote.allowAnyHosts = true

pipeline {
    agent any
    environment{
        PI_CREDS=credentials('ec2-user')

    }

        tools
    {
       maven "maven-3.9.6"
    }
    stages {
        stage('checkout') {
           steps {

                git branch: 'master', url: 'https://github.com/mariancap/world.git'

          }
        }

        stage('Execute Maven') {
           steps {

                sh 'mvn clean install'
          }
        }

    }
    post{
       always{
            sleep 5
        }
    }
}

When i run the job it start to freeze and the entire page stops working. Here is where the job blocks:
    + mvn clean install
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [WARNING] 
    [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example.maven-project:server:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [WARNING] Reporting configuration should be done in <reporting> section, not in maven-site-plugin <configuration> as reportPlugins parameter.
    [WARNING] 
    [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example.maven-project:webapp:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [WARNING] Reporting configuration should be done in <reporting> section, not in maven-site-plugin <configuration> as reportPlugins parameter.
    [WARNING] 
    [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example.maven-project:maven-project:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [WARNING] Reporting configuration should be done in <reporting> section, not in maven-site-plugin <configuration> as reportPlugins parameter. @ line 58, column 24
    [WARNING] 
    [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
    [WARNING] 
    [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
    [WARNING] 
    [WARNING] The project com.example.maven-project:maven-project:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] Maven Project                                                      [pom]
    [INFO] Server                                                             [jar]
    [INFO] Webapp                                                             [war]
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --------------< com.example.maven-project:maven-project >---------------
    [INFO] Building Maven Project 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                [1/3]
    [INFO]   from pom.xml
    [INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ maven-project ---
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- install:3.1.1:install (default-install) @ maven-project ---
    [INFO] Installing /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/pom.xml to /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/example/maven-project/maven-project/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] ------------------< com.example.maven-project:server >------------------
    [INFO] Building Server 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                       [2/3]
    [INFO]   from server/pom.xml
    [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ server ---
    [INFO] Deleting /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/server/target
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- resources:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ server ---
    [debug] execute contextualize
    [INFO] Using 'utf-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/server/src/main/resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- compiler:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ server ---
    [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/server/target/classes
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- resources:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ server ---
    [debug] execute contextualize
    [INFO] Using 'utf-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/server/src/test/resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- compiler:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ server ---
    [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/server/target/test-classes
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- surefire:2.11:test (default-test) @ server ---
    [INFO] Surefire report directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/server/target/surefire-reports

    -------------------------------------------------------
     T E S T S
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Running com.example.TestGreeter
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.099 sec

    Results :

    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- jar:3.3.0:jar (default-jar) @ server ---
    [INFO] Building jar: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/server/target/server.jar
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- install:3.1.1:install (default-install) @ server ---
    [INFO] Installing /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/server/pom.xml to /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/example/maven-project/server/1.0-SNAPSHOT/server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
    [INFO] Installing /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/server/target/server.jar to /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/example/maven-project/server/1.0-SNAPSHOT/server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] ------------------< com.example.maven-project:webapp >------------------
    [INFO] Building Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                       [3/3]
    [INFO]   from webapp/pom.xml
    [INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ webapp ---
    [INFO] Deleting /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/webapp/target
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- resources:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ webapp ---
    [debug] execute contextualize
    [INFO] Using 'utf-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/webapp/src/main/resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- compiler:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ webapp ---
    [INFO] No sources to compile
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- resources:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ webapp ---
    [debug] execute contextualize
    [INFO] Using 'utf-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/webapp/src/test/resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- compiler:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ webapp ---
    [INFO] No sources to compile
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- surefire:2.11:test (default-test) @ webapp ---
    [INFO] No tests to run.
    [INFO] Surefire report directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/webapp/target/surefire-reports

    -------------------------------------------------------
     T E S T S
    -------------------------------------------------------

Can the problem be related to the node ? 
I had this problem with the node from the beggining of using Jenkins, but i had no problems with another jobs
And i will show you also the pom.xml file
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.example.maven-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Webapp</name>
<description>Webapp.</description>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>

It has been not updated from 6 years ago, i just forked the code from another git hub account
